# How to create multiple json files from multiple cucumber tests

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber

The below cucumber runner class generates a JSON file. This JSON is then used to generate a cucumber report.

I have since added a new *.feature* file to my resources.

Both sets of tests in the feature files pass, but the problem is that a second JSON file is not being generated, so my second set of results are not being recorded.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"progress",
            "html:build/report/cucumber/html",
            "junit:build/report/cucumber/junit/cucumber.xml",
            "json:build/report/cucumber/json/cucumber.json"
    },
    glue = {"com.commercial.tests"},
            features = {"src/test/resources/templates"},
            tags = {"@BR000, @BR002a, @BR002b, @BR003, @BR004, @BR004b, @BR005, @BR006, @BR007, @BR008", "not @wip"}
    )
public class QARunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Above, I specify to create **cucumber.json**, but how do I specify a second json file for the second .feature?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: The above code works, the 1 json file creates 2 results (1 per feature file).

So there is no need to add a second JSON file in the annotation at the top of the class.